# sql query to calculate the time difference between the two successive rows

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone help me to calculate the time difference(in `hh:mm`) between the two rows, when the `Procs_ID` changes from 01 to another `Procs_ID`.

```
Procs_ID  meter_id        date
  01      0000012         2015-10-12 09:07:22.530
  03      0000013         2015-10-12 09:11:51.733
  01      0000014         2015-10-12 09:12:38.550
  02      0000015         2015-10-12 10:38:52.923
  03      0000016         2015-10-12 10:40:33.467
  01      0000017         2015-10-12 10:40:56.013
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do this using Lag/Lead in SQL Server

Comment: Can you also post your expected output?

Comment: What SQL version are you using? The methods to use vary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with `LEAD` which is avaliable for SQL Server 2012+

```
select
    *,
    case 
        when Procs_Id = '01' 
             and lead(Procs_ID) over (order by [date]) <> Procs_ID then datediff(mi,[date],lead([date]) over (order by [date])) 
    end as TimeDiffInMin
from YourTable
```

Comment: HI scsimon, I am using MS Sql server, I am getting the error as 'lead' is not a recognized built-in function name. Thanks